# Как отредактировать чужой апк в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, apk

Читал, что для работы с приложениями, точнее, *над* приложениями, используют прогу под названием Android Studio. Но не знаю, как. И плюс было бы круто если бы был способ обойтись без компа, т.е. сделать все с мобилы

Моей целью является "подправить" название пакейджа файла, а заодно и номер версии. Дело в том, что у меня на самсунге камера ну капец лагучая, а вот сторонний софт - очень даже ниче так. И вот я вытащил 2 апк файла, у одного имя com.sec.android.camera, у другого net.sourceforge.opencamera.

Я хочу в OpenCamera'вском манифесте поменять имя пакета и изменить версию, чтобы накатом "обновить" системную камеру до сторонней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenCamera'вском

Тогда можно просто скачать исходники с SourceForge и в gradle.build изменить package на нужный Вам. Плюс в манифесте и коде надо автозаменой найти всё связанное с `net.sourceforge.opencamera`.

Но поверх стандартного приложения оно не встанет, см. в конце ответа.

А ниже общая информация по модификации APK:

---

Android Studio обычно используется для создания и сборки приложений при наличии исходного кода.

В Вашем случае есть только APK-файл.
Его нужно декомпилировать с помощью [ApkTool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/releases/tag/v2.6.1), а затем вносить изменения.
В каталоге с разобранным приложением будут:

- Ресурсы (`res/*`),
- Код приложения (`smali/`, `smali_classes2/` ...),
- Двоичные файлы (`assets/`),
- Библиотеки, если есть (`lib/<arch>/`),
- Файлы другого типа, манифест и инфа для apktool (`other`, `AndroidManifest.xml` и `apktool.json` соответственно).

---

При этом привычного Java-кода Вы там не встретите, classes.dex "конвертируется" в Smali - это по сути, ассемблер для Android. Чтобы с таким кодом работать, нужно знать его устройство.
А ресурсы и манифест можно спокойно редактировать.

Пакет можно менять и вручную, заменяя все вхождения в manifest.xml и smali, но лучше пользоваться патчерами по типу [Batch ApkTool + плагин AllInOne](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=557858&view=findpost&p=82533052):

- Декомпилировать,
- Запустить AllInOne,
- Поставить ✓флажок на "Клонировать APK",
- Ввести имя пакета,
- Рекомпилировать,
- Подписать.

**Но без root-прав камеру поверх стандартной поставить не получится, т.к. не будут совпадать подписи!**
Нужно будет применять патч на проверку подписи в packagemanager, например, через [LuckyPatcher](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=298302&view=findpost&p=113802265): Инструменты -> Настройки Xposed -> Включить 2 и 3.

Comment: Я вот до прочтения этого сообщения был уверен что я с LP  на "ты". Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, прикрепить скрины

Comment: @Eagle98755, нужен Xposed для работы этих патчей. https://ibb.co/album/bMLr2D

Comment: Root'a у меня нету, а нельзя тупо "скопировать" подпись?

Comment: @Eagle98755, нет, в APK для каждого файла вычисляется хэш-сумма, и при установке Android её проверяет. Вроде был обходной путь на основе уязвимостей ОС, но статью найти никак не могу, да и пофиксили уже наверное.